# AS3 Frogger Pixel Perfect Collision

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have created a simple AS3 frogger game and used .hitTestObject to test if the frog hits any of the obstacles. This is not effective as the frog hits objects that aren't touching it at all. I am new to AS3 and have no idea where to start with coding for this. Any help would be appreciated!

package {

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.*;
import flash.ui.*;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;

    public class Main extends MovieClip 
    {
        //set variables
        public var frog_spriteInstance:frog_sprite;
        public var safeZoneInstance1 : safeZone;
        public var safeZoneInstance2: safeZone;
        public var safeZoneInstance3 : safeZone;
        public var whitecar : car1;
        public var whitecar1 : car1; 
        public var whitecar2 : car1; 
        public var truck1 : truck_sprite;
        public var truck2: truck_sprite;
        public var redcar : car_sprite;
        public var redcar2 : car_sprite;
        public var redcar3 : car_sprite;
        public var log1 : log_sprite;
        public var log2 : log_sprite;
        public var log3 : log_sprite;
        public var letters : Letters;
        public var letters2 : Letters_2;
        public var letters3 : Letters_3;
        public var letters4 : Letters_4;
        public var health : HealthBar;
        public var firstletter : firstLetter;
        public var secondletter : secondLetter;
        public var thirdletter : thirdLetter;
        public var fourthletter : fourthLetter;

        var mysound:Sound = new (mySound); 


        public function Main()
        {
            // constructor code
            safeZoneInstance1 = new safeZone();
            stage.addChild(safeZoneInstance1);
            safeZoneInstance1.x = 300;
            safeZoneInstance1.y=545

            safeZoneInstance2 = new safeZone();
            stage.addChild(safeZoneInstance2);
            safeZoneInstance2.x = 300;
            safeZoneInstance2.y=300

            safeZoneInstance3 = new safeZone();
            stage.addChild(safeZoneInstance3);
            safeZoneInstance3.x = 300;
            safeZoneInstance3.y=100

            whitecar = new car1();
            stage.addChild(whitecar);
            whitecar.x = 300;
            whitecar.y = 500

            whitecar1 = new car1();
            stage.addChild(whitecar1);
            whitecar1.x = 550;
            whitecar1.y = 480

            whitecar2 = new car1();
            stage.addChild(whitecar2);
            whitecar2.x = 50;
            whitecar2.y = 480

            truck1 = new truck_sprite();
            stage.addChild (truck1);
            truck1.x = 1000;
            truck1.y = 430

            truck2 = new truck_sprite();
            stage.addChild (truck2);
            truck2.x = 300;
            truck2.y = 430

            redcar = new car_sprite();
            stage.addChild (redcar);
            redcar.x = 300;
            redcar.y = 340

            redcar2 = new car_sprite();
            stage.addChild (redcar2);
            redcar2.x = 100;
            redcar2.y = 375

            redcar3 = new car_sprite();
            stage.addChild (redcar3);
            redcar3.x = 500;
            redcar3.y = 375

            log1 = new log_sprite();
            stage.addChild(log1);
            log1.x = 300;
            log1.y = 230

            log2 = new log_sprite();
            stage.addChild(log2);
            log2.x = 100;
            log2.y = 150


            log3 = new log_sprite();
            stage.addChild(log3);
            log3.x = 500;
            log3.y = 150

            letters = new Letters();
            letters.x = randomRange(100,500) ;
            letters.y = randomRange(100,500);
            stage.addChild(letters); 

            letters2 = new Letters_2();
            letters2.x = randomRange(100,500) ;
            letters2.y = randomRange(100,500);
            stage.addChild(letters2); 

            letters3 = new Letters_3();
            letters3.x = randomRange(100,500) ;
            letters3.y = randomRange(100,500);
            stage.addChild(letters3); 

            letters4 = new Letters_4();
            letters4.x = randomRange(100,500) ;
            letters4.y = randomRange(100,500);
            stage.addChild(letters4); 

            frog_spriteInstance = new frog_sprite();
            stage.addChild(frog_spriteInstance);  
            frog_spriteInstance.x=300; 
            frog_spriteInstance.y=550;

            health = new HealthBar();
            stage.addChild(health);
            health.x = 130;
            health.y = 20;
            health.width = 100;

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, moveFrog);

            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movecars); 

            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movetrucks);

            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveredcars);

            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movelogs);

            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkforcollision);

            mysound.play();
        }

        public function moveFrog(e:KeyboardEvent)
        {   
           // get the key pressed and then move the player

            {
                if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
                {
                    frog_spriteInstance.rotation = 0;
                    frog_spriteInstance.y -= 50;
                }
                if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
                {
                    frog_spriteInstance.rotation = 180;
                    frog_spriteInstance.y += 50;
                }
                if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
                {
                    frog_spriteInstance.rotation = -90;
                    frog_spriteInstance.x -= 50;
                }
                if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
                {
                    frog_spriteInstance.rotation = 90;
                    frog_spriteInstance.x += 50;
                }

            }
        }

        function movecars(event:Event)  
        {  
            //move cars across screen and when they disappear, reappear at the other side
            whitecar.x -= 3;  

            if (whitecar.x<-100){
            whitecar.x=650;
            }  
            whitecar1.x -= 3;  

            if (whitecar1.x<-100){
            whitecar1.x=650;
            } 
            whitecar2.x -= 3;  

            if (whitecar2.x<-100){
            whitecar2.x=650;
            } 
        }

        function movelogs(event:Event)  
        {  
            //move logs across screen and when they disappear, reappear at the other side
            log1.x -= 5;  

            if (log1.x<-100){
            log1.x=650;
            }  
            log2.x -= 5;  

            if (log2.x<-100){
            log2.x=650;
            } 
            log3.x -= 5;  

            if (log3.x<-100){
            log3.x=650;
            } 
        }

        function movetrucks(event:Event)
        {
            //move trucks across screen and when they disappear, reappear at the other side
            truck1.x +=3;

        if (truck1.x>650){
            truck1.x=-100;
            }
            truck2.x +=3;

        if (truck2.x>650){
            truck2.x=-100;
            }

        }

        function moveredcars(event:Event)
        {
            //move red cars across screen and when they disappear, reappear at the other side
            redcar.x +=3;

        if (redcar.x>650){
            redcar.x=-100;
            }
            redcar2.x +=3;

        if (redcar2.x>650){
            redcar2.x=-100;
            }
            redcar3.x +=3;

        if (redcar3.x>650){
            redcar3.x=-100;
            }
        }

        function checkforcollision(event:Event)
        {
            //check for collisions
            if (frog_spriteInstance.hitTestObject(log1) || (frog_spriteInstance.hitTestObject(log2) || (frog_spriteInstance.hitTestObject(log3) || (frog_spriteInstance.hitTestObject(whitecar) || (frog_spriteInstance.hitTestObject(whitecar1) || (frog_spriteInstance.hitTestObject(whitecar2) || (frog_spriteInstance.hitTestObject(log2) || (frog_spriteInstance.hitTestObject(truck1) || (frog_spriteInstance.hitTestObject(truck2) || (frog_spriteInstance.hitTestObject(redcar) || (frog_spriteInstance.hitTestObject(redcar2) || (frog_spriteInstance.hitTestObject(redcar3))))))))))))){
            //reset frog if hits an obstacle
            stage.addChild(frog_spriteInstance);  
            frog_spriteInstance.x=300; 
            frog_spriteInstance.y=550;
            //reduce health bar
            health.width -= 10;
            }
            //remove event listeners when health is empty
            if (health.width == 0){
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movecars);
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, moveFrog);
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movetrucks);
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveredcars);
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movelogs);
            }
            //add letters to bottom of screen when hit correctly
            if (frog_spriteInstance.hitTestObject(letters)){
                stage.addChild(frog_spriteInstance);  
                frog_spriteInstance.x=300; 
                frog_spriteInstance.y=550;
                stage.removeChild(letters);
                firstletter = new firstLetter();
                stage.addChild(firstletter);
                firstletter.x=345; 
                firstletter.y=600; 
            }
            if (frog_spriteInstance.hitTestObject(letters2)){
                stage.addChild(frog_spriteInstance);  
                frog_spriteInstance.x=300; 
                frog_spriteInstance.y=550;
                stage.removeChild(letters2);
                secondletter = new secondLetter();
                stage.addChild(secondletter);
                secondletter.x=206; 
                secondletter.y=600; 

            }
            if (frog_spriteInstance.hitTestObject(letters3)){
                stage.addChild(frog_spriteInstance);  
                frog_spriteInstance.x=300; 
                frog_spriteInstance.y=550;
                stage.removeChild(letters3);
                thirdletter = new thirdLetter();
                stage.addChild(thirdletter);
                thirdletter.x=273; 
                thirdletter.y=600; 

            }
            if (frog_spriteInstance.hitTestObject(letters4)){
                stage.addChild(frog_spriteInstance);  
                frog_spriteInstance.x=300; 
                frog_spriteInstance.y=550;
                stage.removeChild(letters4);
                health.width -= 10;
                fourthletter = new fourthLetter();
                stage.addChild(fourthletter);
                fourthletter.x=25; 
                fourthletter.y=620; 
            }
        }

        function randomRange(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number 
        {
            //random generator for letter positioning
            return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
        }
   }
```

}

Also my code is pretty dodgy so any suggestions on improvement are very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform pixel perfect hit test from two arbitrary display objects you have to draw them to bitmaps and use [`BitmapData/hitTest()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#hitTest()).

Here is a generalized function that does this:

```
function hitTestShapes(object1:DisplayObject, object2:DisplayObject, threshold:uint = 1):Boolean {

    var bounds1:Rectangle = object1.getBounds(object1.parent);
    var matrix1:Matrix = object1.transform.matrix;
    matrix1.tx = object1.x - bounds1.x;
    matrix1.ty = object1.y - bounds1.y;
    var bmp1:BitmapData = new BitmapData(bounds1.width, bounds1.height, true, 0);
    bmp1.draw(object1, matrix1);

    var bounds2:Rectangle = object2.getBounds(object2.parent);
    var matrix2:Matrix = object2.transform.matrix;
    matrix2.tx = object2.x - bounds2.x;
    matrix2.ty = object2.y - bounds2.y;
    var bmp2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(bounds2.width, bounds2.height, true, 0);
    bmp2.draw(object2, matrix2);

    return bmp1.hitTest(bounds1.topLeft, threshold, bmp2, bounds2.topLeft, threshold);
}
```

Note, though, that drawing to bitmaps is rather slow, so be careful not to over-use this kind of function or you will have performance issues. In fact, it would be a good idea to use `hitTestObject()` first, which is very fast and detects bounding box intersections, then only call `hitTestShapes()` to refine your check. In other words:

```
if (frog_spriteInstance.hitTestObject(log1) && hitTestShapes(frog_spriteInstance, log1)) { }
```

---

As for suggestions on your code, there's a lot of potential for de-duplicating by way of arrays, loops, and functions. For example, instead of defining all your objects as separate variables, just store them all in an array (or vector):

```
public var safeZones:Array = [];
public var obstacles:Array = [];
public var letters:Array = [];
```

To populate the arrays, you can push values into them and use a function to consolidate all your duplicate object setup code:

*(Code convention note: use "UpperCamelCase" for class names.)*

```
public function Main(){
    addSafeZone(300, 545);
    addSafeZone(300, 300);
    addSafeZone(300, 100);

    addObstacle(WhiteCar, 300, 500);
    addObstacle(WhiteCar, 550, 480);
    addObstacle(WhiteCar, 50, 480);

    addObstacle(Truck, 1000, 430);
    addObstacle(Truck, 300, 430);

    addObstacle(RedCar, 300, 340);
    addObstacle(RedCar, 100, 375);
    addObstacle(RedCar, 500, 375);

    addObstacle(Log, 300, 230);
    addObstacle(Log, 100, 150);
    addObstacle(Log, 500, 150);

    addRandomLetters(Letters_1);
    addRandomLetters(Letters_2);
    addRandomLetters(Letters_3);
    addRandomLetters(Letters_4);
}

private function addSafeZone(x:Number, y:Number):void {
    var safeZone:SafeZone = new SafeZone();
    stage.addChild(safeZone);
    safeZone.x = x;
    safeZone.y = y
    safeZones.push(safeZone);
}

private function addObstacle(spriteClass:Class, x:Number, y:Number):void {
    var obstacle:Sprite = new spriteClass();
    stage.addChild(obstacle);
    obstacle.x = x;
    obstacle.y = y
    obstacles.push(obstacle);
}

private function addRandomLetters(lettersClass:Class):void {
    var lettersSprite:Sprite = new lettersClass();
    lettersSprite.x = randomRange(100, 500);
    lettersSprite.y = randomRange(100, 500);
    stage.addChild(lettersSprite); 
    letters.push(lettersSprite);
}
```

Now you can loop over the arrays to perform all your actions. For example, to check for a hit against any obstacle:

```
for each(var obstacle:DisplayObject in obstacles){
    if(frog.hitTestObject(obstacle) && hitTestShapes(frog, obstacle)){
        // The frog hit an obstacle!
    }
}
```

You could also combine all our "move" functions into one, which moves each obstacle based on their type:

```
private function moveObstacles(e:Event):void {
    for each(var obstacle in obstacles){
        if(obstacle is WhiteCar){
            obstacle.x -= 3;
        }
        else if(obstacle is RedCar){
            obstacle.x += 3;
        }
        else if(obstacle is Truck){
            obstacle.x += 3;
        }
        else if(obstacle is Log){
            obstacle.x -= 5;
        }

        if(obstacle.x < -100){
            obstacle.x = 650;
        }
        else if(obstacle.x > 650){
            obstacle.x = -100;
        }

    }
}
```

Lastly, you really should only need a single `ENTER_FRAME` handler. Just call whatever functions you want from in there. Adding multiple `ENTER_FRAME` handlers can get troublesome to manage. For example, just do this:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

private function update(e:Event):void {
    moveObstacles();
    doOtherStuff();
    anythingYouNeedToDo();
}
```

This way you only need to `removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update)` to stop the game, not a whole bunch of `ENTER_FRAME` handlers.

I haven't tested any of this code, but you get the general idea. Let me know if you have any issues with it and I can help.

Comment: thanks so much for that! Code is working well now, however I'm getting an error when trying to add the frog and keyboard listeners to make it move now. What's the best way to get it moving?